# At what point can the consumer in a pipeline slow down the producer?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Say we have `a | b`, under what circumstances could `b` slow down `a`? If `b` was a CPU hog, that would do it...what if `b` was consuming stdin really slowly? are there other factors?

Comment: `yes | tail -f /dev/null` will slow down `yes` to a halt. `yes > /dev/null` will let if peg the cpu to 100%. Now you know under which circumstances that could happen. And no, `b` being a CPU hog won't slow `a` down if both are single-threaded and your system gives each of them its own CPU to hump on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if `b` was using resources (CPU, disk, memory, file descriptors etc.) that `a` also needed, or if `b` held any type of lock on files or in databases that `a` was trying to acquire, this would *possibly* slow down `a` (or even cause `a` to fail).

The `a` process would simply block while trying to write to `b` if `b` did not read what it was writing fast enough.  This is, I believe, the more common scenario.